# How to bind to a collection of collections to display informationon a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a `List<List<string>>` to a `DataGrid` programatically. I'm using
this `List<List<string>>` because the `DataGrid` has to have a variable number of columns.

Actually, I got to bind the `DataGrid` to an `string[][]` but it is partially useful because there will be the need to get this data structure and add rows to it, that's why I want to use a `List<List<string>>`.

Currently, I'm using this snippet to generate the columns.

```
dgResults.Columns.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
    dgResults.Columns.Add(textColumn);
}
```

What should I use on `textColumn.Binding` in order to bind to a `List<list<string>>`?

Comment: The data-binding system doesn't support that.

Comment: @SLaks what do you recommend then? should I get `ItemsSource` contents, cast them to an `string[]` and use it to update the `ItemsSource` by instantiating a new `string[][]` containing the initial data?

Comment: I think the easiest way to bind DataGrid to a collection of objects whose properties are known only at runtime is to bind DataGrid to DataTable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

Comment: What does the Xaml look like; what is shown for the inner list?

Comment: I think you are going to need to use Path on the Binding.   I am doing this on a GridView to bind to columns to a collection of objects where that collection size varies.  This is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... I was using the `string[][]` structure... but with the snippet I wrote, `List<List<string>>` can be used to the intended purpose!